# what is wrong in this java code on inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
package inheritencelatest;
public class InheritenceLatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        person p1=new person(12,"ekaf","atlanta","male");
        employe e1=new employe(23,"ekaf","atlanta","male",12000);       

         e1.ageCategory();
         e1.genderIdentity();
         e1.display();
         ((employe)p1).display();
       }

}

 class person {
      int age;
      String name;
      String Address;
      String ageGroup;
      protected String  gender;
      private String canNotBeAccesed;    //cant be accessed by subclass    

      person(int age,String name,String Address,String gender) {
          this.age=age;
          this.name=name;
          this.Address=Address;
          this.gender=gender;
      }

      String ageCategory() { 
          if(age<10)
          return("kid");
          else if(age<20 &&age>10)
          return("Teen");
          else if(age<50&&age>20)
          return("adult");
          else
          return("senior");
       }

     protected void genderIdentity() {
       if("male".equals(gender))
       System.out.println("male");
       else if(gender=="female")
       System.out.println("female");
       else 
       System.out.println("Special");
     }

 }


class employe extends person {
    double salary;

    employe(int age,String name,String Address,String gender,int salary) {
       super(age,name,Address,gender);
       this.salary=salary;
       this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    protected  void genderIdentity() { 
       if(gender=="male")
          salary=salary;
       if(gender=="female")
          salary=1.5*salary;
       else 
          salary=2*salary;    
    }

    void display() {
       System.out.println(age +" " +name+" "+Address+" "+salary+" "+gender+ " "+ageGroup);
    }
```

}

when i run this code i get output as :

male
 23  ekaf  atlanat  24000.0  male  null

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:inheritencelatest.person cannot be cast to inheritencelatest.employe at inheritencelatest.InheritenceLatest.main(InheritenceLatest.java:17)**

***MY DOUBTS ARE***

how does the salary becomes 24000?                                                         Why does the agecategory is null , didn't object e1 get value of ageGroup when i write e1.agecategory?                                                            Why does ((employe)p1).display(); is raising exception ?

What could be the use of
person p2=new employe(23,"ekaf","atlanat","male",12000);?

Comment: `p1` is a `person`, not a `employer`.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when you post it. It's all over the place at the moment - and this doesn't like a *minimal* example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You should also read read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832

Comment: You cannot cast a Class to a Subclass. You can the other way around, but that won't change the code that will be executed.

Comment: what is the expected op?

Comment: You should pay attention to naming conventions too. A class name always starts with an uppercase letter, and the attributes/variables names starts always with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the recommendations:) i will make sure next time i pay more focus :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how salary becomes 24000?

In the genderIdentity() method of your employe class, you use `==` to compare `gender` to `"male"`. This condition is false, because `gender` and `"male"` are different String objects (even if they have the same contents/text). You should use `.equals()` to compare the two Strings instead. Now, the salary gets doubled because neither `gender == "male"` nor `gender == "female"` returns true.

> why the agecategory is null didnt object e1 get age category when i write e1.agecategory?

When you write `e1.agecategory()`, you call the method named `agecategory()`. This method only returns a String object, but doesn't actually do anything else with it. You don't have any code anywhere that assigns a value to the `agegroup` variable (which would have to look like `agegroup = <something>;`, so the variable keeps its default value of `null`.

> why ((employe)p1).display(); is raising exception ?

It's because, with `(employe)p1`, you try to cast the `p1` object to the `employe` type. This cannot be done because `p1` was defined only to be a `person`, and not an `employe`. The other way around would work fine, because by writing `class employe extends person`, every `employe` is known to also be a `person`.

> what could be the use of
>   person p2=new employe(23,"ekaf","atlanat","male",12000);

Doing this can be useful because you are creating a variable `p2` that can reference any kind of `person`, and it is not limited to only referencing `employe` objects. This is useful in, for example, cases where you want to be able to handle any kind of `person`. Java does still remember that this particular person is an employe though, so you can cast it to the more specific `employe` type later and call `employe`-specific methods on it.

Comment: thank you so much for the answers . it worked and helped me a lot :)